# Testing the behavior of a page through a named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

I have a named route for narrowing the index action to a particular week

```
match "workouts/week/(:date)" => "workouts#index", 
  :constraints => { :date => /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ },
  :as => "workouts_date"
```

I'm trying to write a spec to test that the index view properly shows only the given weeks workouts.

```
  it 'populates an array of workouts for the week of the given date' do
    sunday_workout = FactoryGirl.create(:workout, date: Date.new(2012, 12, 31).beginning_of_week(:sunday))
    today_workout = FactoryGirl.create(:workout, date: Date.new(2012, 12, 31))
    saturday_workout = FactoryGirl.create(:workout, date: Date.new(2012, 12, 31).end_of_week(:sunday))
    next_week_workout = FactoryGirl.create(:workout, date: Date.new(2012, 12, 31).next_week)
    prev_week_workout = FactoryGirl.create(:workout, date: Date.new(2012, 12, 31).prev_week)
    this_week_workouts = [sunday_workout, today_workout, saturday_workout].group_by(&:date)
    get 'workouts/week/2012-12-31'
    assigns(:workouts).should eq this_weeks_workouts
  end
```

I get the error:

```
Failure/Error: get 'workouts/week/2012-12-31'
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   The action 'workouts/week/2012-12-31' could not be found for WorkoutsController
```

The action is index, but I don't know how to make it route there other than providing the `:index` symbol.

EDIT: I added the following to the spec_helper file:

```
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

and changed the get request to

```
get workouts_date_path('2012-12-31')
```

however I still get

```
 The action '/workouts/week/2012-12-31' could not be found for WorkoutsController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a controller test you should call your controller like this: `get 'index', date: '2012-12-31'`. You are testing the controller action, it knows nothing about routing. Makes sense? There are routing specs if you want to test routing.